# Disable button in Child Component after an event in parent component without having to refresh the page for the disable to take effect

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

The code I have works but only after the page refreshes. E.g. I can click on the Continue button and the page would refresh instead of moving forward in the application and now the button will be disabled. But what I am looking for is to have the button disable as soon as a certain value is selected from a drop down in a parent component. The continue button is its own child component as it used in many other components within the application. On angular version 6.

ParentComponent.html

```
... //Select dropdown that sets the disableContinueButton value based on what is selected

<df-child-component
    [forwardOnly]="true"
    [isAppLoading]="isAppLoading"
    [forwardDisabled]="disableContinueButton$ | async"
    [submitButtonText]="'Continue'"
  >
</df-child-component>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
      disableContinueButton$ = of(false);
      ...
      onSelectEvent(){ 
          //Sets the disableContinueButton flag based on what is selcted.
      }
}
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'df-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  forwardOnly: boolean;
  @Input()
  isAppLoading: boolean;
  @Input()
  forwardDisabled: boolean;
  @Input()
  submitButtonText: string;

  @Output()
  back = new EventEmitter();
  @Output()
  forward = new EventEmitter();
}
```

ChildComponent.html

```
      <button
        type="Submit"
        class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2 order-1 order-sm-2 mb-2"
        (click)="forward.emit({})"
        [disabled]="isAppLoading || forwardDisabled"
        id="nav-continue"
      >
        {{ submitButtonText }}
      </button>
```

Comment: How are you updating disableContinueButton$?

Comment: Using a re-assignment:
      this.disableContinueButton$ = of(true);

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this, but my guess is that your change detection is not capturing the change for some reason.

I suggest that you use either `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject` instead of an observable:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
      disableContinueButton$ = new BehaviourSubject(false);
      ...
      onSelectEvent(){ 
          this.disableContinueButton.next(true); // true or false
      }
}
```

If that still does not work, you can force the change detection to run by injecting the `ChangeDetectorRef` and calling `markForCheck` or `detectChanges` on it:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    onSelectEvent(){
        // Update the value
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

using a ViewChild will allow you to fire a function in the child component from the parent component.